# Using XML-RPC in Python 3, how to see if a WordPress post exists by date and category?

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I need to query a WordPress site from Python 3 to see if a WordPress post of custom post type with a specific date and category already exists. Based on [the docs for the the wp.GetPosts](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts) method, this seems to be possible, but I cannot work out the right query. What I'm using currently is:

```
import xmlrpc.client
wp_url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/xmlrpc.php"
server = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(wp_url)

filters = {
            'post_date': start_time, # an RFC-3339 formatted date
            'post_type' : 'my-custom-post-type', 
        }

fields = {
        'terms' : { 
            'category': ['my-category'] 
            }
        }

post_id = server.wp.getPosts(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, filters, fields)
```

(where wp_blogid, wp_username and wp_password are all correctly defined, of course).

What this returns is just a list of ten seemingly-random posts of the correct custom post type, with no further filter applied. Do I need to just get every post and then iterate over them for my terms, or is there an easier way?

Comment: The documentation doesn't list `post_date` as a valid filter.

Comment: The line *Supports same filters as #wp.getPost.* is confusing, since `wp.getPost` doesn't support filtering. I suspect that this is a typo, they meant *fields* instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to filter posts by date, sorry. The documentation is misleading, in that it claims to support the *same filters as `#wp.getPost`*, but the latter has no filtering *at all*; presumably that section confused *fields* with *filters*.

The documentation lists what *is* supported in the argument lists:

> - struct `filter`: Optional.
>
>   - string `post_type`
>   - string `post_status`
>   - int `number`
>   - int `offset`
>   - string `orderby`
>   - string `order`

The [Wordpress XML-RPC source code handling the filters](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aaf99e691391cfceb004d848450dbbf3344b1bee/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php#L1912-L1953) corroborates this.

So using XML-RPC, you have no other option but to page through the results to find the matching posts for the given date.

You should look at the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) instead, the [`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` route](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts) lets you filter posts by date.

Comment: It appears you are exactly right. Your last sentence seems to imply, however, that there may be some alternative to XML-RPC. What might that be? I'm talking about 6,000+ posts here, so paging through the results of a mass query is impractical.

Comment: @NFB: the PHP API offered by Wordpress lets you do much more complex queries, so you could build your own plugin to expose access to that. I'm no WP developer however, I can't really help with that. Then there may be other externally-accessible APIs other than XML-RPC, but I haven't looked into that.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this post, and confirming @Martin Pieters's comment, I can confirm it is a much better approach to use the WordPress API. It can be used in directly Python using the requests module.

Comment: @NFB: ah, yes, I forgot to add that I had found the REST API in the meantime, and the `requests` module is indeed a great way to call it.